# Waking up laptop from cron

Tags: power-management

I want my laptop to wake up at 0300 even with the lid closed, check power & network status and perform certain functions if it is connected.

There's `rtcwake` but I don't want to use it to suspend: I just want to use the lid.

I looked through APM manual and there is something that looks like what I need: Get/Set/Disable Resume Timer (11H). How can I use it? I presume this is what rtcwake does.

(XPS 13 2016 with ubuntu 16.10)

Comment: rtcwake programs the RTC chip to wake up the system; from what I recall from my assembly days the timer chip while interesting is a different beast.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I looked at rtcwake source code and it handles sleep via shutdown. Do you know if if timer will wake my laptop up if I simply set it up without shutting down? I was thinking maybe a cron job that ensures the timer is set?

Comment: The RTC chipset keeps working while the CPU is not working; the timer chipset does not; as simple as that. The RTC simply sets an alarm and sends an interrupt at the alarm time to wake your computer. There is no way around that.